# (Custom multiplication table) Numeric Value is greater than 1.79769E+308 and can not be displayed properly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I'm working on a custom function that converts between unit quantities.

It should look determine the cell in A1, and use that as a search key across the first row in another tab. Once it finds the cell matching A1 from the previous tab, it records that number as the index to return for a 'vlookup' function

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DgdggqfKRiuKsJWYSiMKl57ZkpuCZDWxyZKV7T2zzHU/edit?usp=sharing

```
 function uConvert( quantity, sourceUnit, targetUnit )
{
  var accountName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).getValue(); //determine the account name to use in the horizontal search
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tableSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Productivity Standards");
  var tableData = tableSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var numColumns = tableSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sourceSpot = 0;
  var targetSpot = 0;
  
  
  // searches across row 1 to find which column to perform the multiplication/division
  for (var accountSpot = 0; accountSpot<numColumns; ++accountSpot){ 
    if (tableData[0][accountSpot]==accountName){break};
    }
    
    
  for ( var tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < tableData.length; ++tableIndex )
  {  
    var unit = tableData[tableIndex][0];
    if ( unit == sourceUnit )
    {
      sourceSpot = tableIndex;
    }
    if ( unit == targetUnit )
    {
      targetSpot = tableIndex;
    }
  }
if ( sourceSpot == 0 || targetSpot == 0 )
  {
    return "One or more units not in table";  
  }
  
  var convertedAmount = 0;
  if ( sourceSpot > targetSpot )
  {
    convertedAmount = convertHigherToLower( tableData, sourceSpot, targetSpot, quantity, accountSpot ); 
  }

  else if ( sourceSpot < targetSpot )
  {
    convertedAmount = convertLowerToHigher( tableData, sourceSpot, targetSpot, quantity, accountSpot );
  }
  else
  {
    return quantity;
  }
  return convertedAmount;
}

function convertHigherToLower( data, startIndex, endIndex, startingAmount, columnToSearch )
{

  // we're decending so we're multiplying
  // ( 3 pallets x 20 cartons per pallet x 30 pieces per carton = 1800 )

  var convertedQuantity = startingAmount;

  for ( var dataIndex = startIndex; dataIndex > endIndex; --dataIndex )
  {
    convertedQuantity *= data[dataIndex][columnToSearch];     
  }

  return convertedQuantity;

}

function convertLowerToHigher( data, startIndex, endIndex, startingAmount, columnToSearch )
{

  // we're ascending so we're dividing
  // Assume:
  // 300 pieces is 10 cartons is 0.5 pallets
  // this will be a ratio
  // the ratio will be starting amount ( 300 ) divided by the
  // remainder of the conversion amounts of the table
  // starting from the next higher thing on the table ( startIndex + 1 )
  // to the end of table
  // 300 /  20 / 30 
  // 15 / 30
  // equals 0.5

  var conversionAmount = startingAmount;

  for ( var dataIndex = startIndex + 1; dataIndex <= endIndex; ++dataIndex ) 
  {
    conversionAmount /= data[dataIndex][columnToSearch]; 
  }

  return conversionAmount;

}
```

In the example

## NUM!

Error: Numeric value is greater than 1.79769E+308 and cannot be displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth providing some error checking in your code like this and perhaps you might know of others since your more familiar with what your doing.  Since your getting large numbers it's worth considering the possibility of division by zero.

```
function uConvert( quantity, sourceUnit, targetUnit ) {
  if(quantity && sourceUnit && targetUnit) {
    var accountName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).getValue(); //determine the account name to use in the horizontal search
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var tableSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Productivity Standards");
    var tableData = tableSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var numColumns = tableSheet.getLastColumn();
    var sourceSpot = 0;
    var targetSpot = 0;
    for (var accountSpot = 0; accountSpot<numColumns; ++accountSpot){ 
      if (tableData[0][accountSpot]==accountName){break};
    }
    for(var tableIndex=0;tableIndex<tableData.length;tableIndex++) {  
      var unit=tableData[tableIndex][0];
      if(unit==sourceUnit) {
        sourceSpot=tableIndex;
      }
      if(unit==targetUnit)
      {
        targetSpot=tableIndex;
      }
    }
    if(sourceSpot==0||targetSpot==0) {
      return "One or more units not in table";  
    }
    var convertedAmount=0;
    if (sourceSpot>targetSpot){
      convertedAmount=convertHigherToLower(tableData,sourceSpot,targetSpot,quantity,accountSpot); 
    }else if(sourceSpot<targetSpot){
      convertedAmount=convertLowerToHigher(tableData,sourceSpot,targetSpot,quantity,accountSpot);
    }else{
      return quantity;
    }
    return convertedAmount;
  }else{
    throw("Invalid Inputs in uConvert");
  }
}

function convertHigherToLower( data, startIndex, endIndex, startingAmount, columnToSearch ) {
  if(data && startIndex>-1 && endIndex>-1 && startingAmount && columnToSearch) {
    var convertedQuantity = startingAmount;
    for (var dataIndex=startIndex;dataIndex>endIndex;dataIndex--) {
      convertedQuantity*=data[dataIndex][columnToSearch];     
    }
    return convertedQuantity;
  }else{
    throw("Invalid Inputs in convertHigherToLower");
  }
}

function convertLowerToHigher( data, startIndex, endIndex, startingAmount, columnToSearch ) {
  if(data && startIndex>-1 && endIndex>-1 && startingAmount && columnToSearch) {
    var conversionAmount = startingAmount;
    for(var dataIndex=startIndex + 1;dataIndex<=endIndex;++dataIndex) {
      if(data[dataIndex][columnToSearch]) {
        conversionAmount/=data[dataIndex][columnToSearch]; 
      }else{
        throw("Invalid Divisor in convertLowerToHigher");
      }
    }
    return conversionAmount;
  }else{
    throw("Invalid Inputs in convertLowerToHigher");
  }
}
```